# Constrain child relation by current parent id laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having four tables which are;

- report: fields; id, name,programme_id
- programme: fields; id, name
- weights: fields; id, programme_id, attribute
- compliance: fields: id,weight_id,report_id,compliance_id

A report belongs to a programme, a programme has many weights and each weights belongs to many compliance compliance what i want is getting all compliance under each weight for a given report.

Here is what i have tried;

```
public function allReports(): Builder
    {
        return static::with(['programme.weights.compliance'=>function($q){
            $q->whereColumn('report_id','reports.id');
        }]);
    }
```

but i keep getting the response:

> `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reports.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select` quality_compliances`.*,` report_quality_compliances`.`programme_weight_id`as`pivot_programme_weight_id`,` report_quality_compliances`.`quality_compliance_id`as`pivot_quality_compliance_id`,` report_quality_compliances`.`percentage`as`pivot_percentage`,` report_quality_compliances`.`report_id`as`pivot_report_id`from`quality_compliances`inner join`report_quality_compliances`on`quality_compliances`.`id`=`report_quality_compliances`.`quality_compliance_id`where`report_quality_compliances`.`programme_weight_id`in (53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61) and`report_id`=`reports`.`id`and`quality_compliances`.`deleted_at `is null)",`

Comment: From query it looks like reports table is missing how about `Report::with` this

Comment: Yea am in the report class so i can use the static to replace report